# View New Form With Populated data after Clicking specific DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid

What I am trying to accomplish is opening a new windows form with my sqlite data already populated when the student name is clicked, to edit or delete data. 
How can I populate the data in the edit form when the specific row is clicked? The link to the Edit form is already created.

[image]

After any first name in the first name column is clicked, the following windows open.

[image]

I am assuming that has something to do with my cell content click function, how can I implement it?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_2(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string ExePath = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
        string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(ExePath);

        if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            editStudent editStudent = new editStudent();
            editStudent.Show();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex != 6)  //ignore header row and any column that doesnt have file name
          return;

            var fileName = @"" + drive + "WindowsFormsApplication1\\PDF\\" + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "\\" + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + ".pdf";

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Process.Start(fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist");
            }
    }
```

Comment: `editStudent.ShowDialog()` ?

Comment: This is a windows forms question not a wpf question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out..

```
            editStudent editStudent = new editStudent();
            editStudent.firstName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["First Name"].Value.ToString();
            editStudent.ShowDialog();
```

This is the code i used in the cell content click function.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: forgot to mention, set the textboxes modifiers to public.